# ir filter on the camera

Tags: camera

I am wanting to know if there is an infrared filter on the Raspberry Pi camera. I am wanting to use the Raspberry Pi for infrared photography but some cameras have a filter that blocks out the infrared spectrum.

Is the raspberry pi camera useful for infrared photography?

Answer (score 4):

They now have 2 versions of the Raspberry Pi camera. One with the IR filter and one without:

https://www.adafruit.com/products/1367
and
https://www.adafruit.com/products/1567

Both are official and available from other distributors.

Answer (score 2):

I think all cameras have an infrared filter.

But you can easily remove the filter from the camera board. See this post: http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/4088

Comment: Yes that looks "very easy" indeed..?!

Answer (score 2):

All digital cameras have infrared filters, some are more sophisticated than others.  The cheaper cameras usually only have a thin red covering which you can scratch off the lens with your fingernail to remove the IR filter.  Others are integrated into the lens and cannot be removed.
Saying that it is possible to test the level (in a non-quantitative way) of IR filtering.  Most cheaper digital camera still allow some IR through their filters which may be all you need.  Just find yourself a TV remote control or similar that that an LED IR bulb visible and point this at the camera and press any button.  You should see it change colour, if the filter isn't too powerful, thus saving you the need to remove the IR filter altogether.

Previously I have found that PC line webcam PCL-300K was suitable for converting into an IR camera.  Although I am not sure if this will work with the Pi.